# if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None: в Django

Tags: python, django

Ребят! Пытаюсь сделать форму публикации объявления, с изображениями через modelformset_factory, в итоге выскакивает следующая ошибка: **if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'KeyError' object has no attribute 'get'**

В чем может быть проблема? Дайте наводку?
Вьюха (закоментил на каком моменте выскакивает):

```
def add_classified(request):
ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(ClassifiedImages, fields=('image',), extra=3)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddClassifiedForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        classified = form.save(commit=False)
        classified.author = request.user
        classified.save()
        for f in formset:
            try:
                #сразу после объявления следующей строчки, выходит ошибка.
                photo = ClassifiedImages(classified=classified, image=f.cleaned_data['image'])
                photo.save()
            except Exception as e:
                print('Ошибка')
                return e
        return redirect(classified)
else:
    form = AddClassifiedForm()
    formset = ImageFormset(queryset=ClassifiedImages.objects.none())
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'add_classified.html', context)
```

Comment: Ну так вы в строчке `return e` возвращаете джанге что попало

Comment: Да, точно! Спасибо большое!